# how to transpose only part of a dataframe or interchange rows and columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

the input dataframe is this:

```
branch   Round   letter   var1   var2   var3
  A        1       a       1      2     4
  A        1       b       3      4     5
  B        2       a       6      7     9
  B        2       b       2      3     8
```

I want to interchange only column 3 i.e. 'letter' with columns 'var1', 'var2', 'var3' like this:

Output Dataframe:

```
branch   Round   category   a   b
  A        1        var1    1   3
  A        1        var2    2   4
  A        1        var3    4   5
  B        2        var1    6   2
  B        2        var2    7   3
  B        2        var3    9   8
```

How to do this using pandas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first set `['letter', 'branch']` as index and then use `stack()`.

```
(
    df.set_index(['letter', 'branch']).T
    .stack()
    .reset_index(level=0)
    .sort_index()
    .rename(columns={'level_0':'category'})
)

letter  category    a   b
branch          
A       var1        1   3
A       var2        2   4
A       var3        4   5
B       var1        6   2
B       var2        7   3
B       var3        9   8
```

Comment: I have edited the question, as I have some problem again, as you can see, if I have two columns to be fixed, then how to do it?

Comment: It might be better to ask it as a new question rather than update this one as it might invalidate all the answers here.

Answer (score 2):

set branch and letter as index, then stack the dataframe, and unstack at level 1. You can reset the index if needed.

```py
>>>  (df.set_index(['branch', 'letter'])
    .stack()
    .unstack(1)
    .reset_index(-1)
    .rename(columns={'level_1':'category'}))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
letter category  a  b
branch               
A          var1  1  3
A          var2  2  4
A          var3  4  5
B          var1  6  2
B          var2  7  3
B          var3  9  8
```

You can even use `DataFrame.pivot` along with `stack`:

```py
>>> df.pivot('branch', 'letter').stack(0)

letter       a  b
branch           
A      var1  1  3
       var2  2  4
       var3  4  5
B      var1  6  2
       var2  7  3
       var3  9  8
```

Comment: same idea : ``df.pivot('branch', 'letter').stack(0)``

Comment: @sammywemmy, I was also thinking about pivoting, but I ended up with stack and unstack But I edited the answer with the solution you have provided as well.